# Msg 30007, Level 16 dm_fts_index_keywords, dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document, dm_fts_index_keywords_by_property

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

I have a complex problem with sql server database, if anyone could help me, it would be great.

In my sql server 2014 express, i create a simple database with 3 tables :

- "DocumentFile", "DocumentSearchTerm", "SearchTerm" and a full search text catalog FTCat including 3 columns of the "DocumentFile" table (ExtractText, FileNameWithoutExtension,FilePath)

And i've also created [Search] Store Procedure (and additional sql functions) to perform full search catalog. 
(I share my sql server database backup :  https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlUHN_KmzBqksIs9ylWc5eKBvF1Tgg  in order to test)

When i run on my sql server express local this following script :

```
DECLARE @return_value int,
        @TotalRecords int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[Search]
        @SearchTerm = N'c++',
        @CurrentPage = 1,
        @PageSize = 20,
        @TotalRecords = @TotalRecords OUTPUT

SELECT  @TotalRecords as N'@TotalRecords'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

It runs well and it retunrs me 2 rows.

Now my problem is that i subscribed a smarterasp.net hosting plan including a sql server 2016 database with full search text catalog.

So i restored the backup on my hosted database (it run sucessfully), all the tables, stored procedures, functions and my full search text catalog was created successfully.

But now when i execute the same script :

```
DECLARE @return_value int,
        @TotalRecords int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[Search]
        @SearchTerm = N'c++',
        @CurrentPage = 1,
        @PageSize = 20,
        @TotalRecords = @TotalRecords OUTPUT

SELECT  @TotalRecords as N'@TotalRecords'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

It falied with following message error :

Msg 30007, Level 16, State 1, Line 20
Parameters of dm_fts_index_keywords, dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document, dm_fts_index_keywords_by_property, and dm_fts_index_keywords_position_by_document cannot be null.

Is anybody met this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Sql server throw an error and for me it's not normal , it must just return null.

I explain you what was the problem :

in my stored procedure [GetMainTags] , i writed the name of the dabase hardcoded (the old name of my sql server local) :

DECLARE @db_id int = db_id(N'semanticsdb');

So it's false. In my new database i must write :

DECLARE @db_id int = db_id(N'my_new_database_name');

and to be more generic i must do that for the current database whose execute the function :

declare @dbName varchar (100); 
SELECT @dbName = DB_NAME();
DECLARE @db_id int = db_id(@dbName);